# Using *ngIf on a directive

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I have a `mat-icon` and a `mat-badge` on it containing a number.

I'm looking for removing the `mat-badge` only if the number is `<=0`.

I did `*ngIf` on the entire `mat-icon`, the result its obvious, it remove both `mat-icon` and `mat-badge`.

Here is the code

```
<mat-icon matBadge="{{matBadge}}" class="icon">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `matBadgeHidden` input property of `matBadge` directive

```
<mat-icon matBadge="{{matBadge}}" class="icon" [matBadgeHidden]="number<=0">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
```

Comment: [matBadgeHidden]="!matBadge"

Answer (score 2):

@displayName answer is so clean, you should go with that but you can also use *ngIf with else incase it ever comes handy.

```
<mat-icon matBadge="{{matBadge}}" class="icon" *ngIf="matBadge > 0; else matBadgeHidden">shopping_cart</mat-icon>

<ng-template #matBadgeHidden>
<mat-icon class="icon">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: its working but does ng-template have some default styles such margin, padding? seems like it have own styles